# how to concatenate several whitespace between two text strings

Tags: sas, string-concatenation, space

'I need add 6 blank spaces between variables a and b like:'
'Ive trie a lot of methods.'

```
data hh;

  %let texto1 = "Hola";
  length texto2 $8;
  texto2 = "   Mundo";
  %let texto3 = "!";
  length mi_variable $6; 
  mi_variable = "      ";
  
  z = cats(&texto1., mi_variable, &texto3.);
d= "a"&"b";
e = catx(' ', "a", "      ", "b");
f = cat("a", repeat(" ", 6), "b");
g = "a" || repeat(" ", 6) || "b";
h = catx(" ", "a", repeat(" ", 6), "b");
run;

proc print data=hh;run;
```

'The outpus is always :'
'a b'

'im expexting this:'
'a      b'

Comment: stackoverflow dont let me put blankcspaces between a and b lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?  I use CATX first arg of 6 spaces.

```
21   data _null_;
22       length texto1-texto2 $8 result $24;
23       texto1 = "Hola";
24       texto2 = "Mundo";
25       result = catx('      ',of texto:);
26
27       put (_all_)(=);
28       put 'NOTE: ' result $char.;
29       put 'NOTE- ' result $hex.;
30       run;

texto1=Hola texto2=Mundo result=Hola      Mundo
NOTE: Hola      Mundo
      486F6C612020202020204D756E646F202020202020202020
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: It seems html output will compress multiple spaces into one. I use `ods listing`, `ods html`, `ods pdf` and `ods rtf` to output the same `proc print`, only in html, six spaces between character `a` and `b` is compressed as one space.